# Joining multiple tables in Aurora mysql and push them to dynamodb single table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-aurora

From my understanding I think there are lots of ways to transfer one mysql table to dynamodb using datapipeline or storing the table in S3 but there is a senario where one table has one id per record and other table has multiple id in a table so it's one to many relationship  but I need this two tables in a single dynamodb table.
for e.g. the dynamodb table will look something like this.
{
'id': 1,
'status' : 'Active',
'scores' : [{'date': '2022', 'score' : 29 }, {'date': '2022', 'score' : 29 }]
}

which I can then fetch the JSON data from dynamodb table via lambda and send them through API. Is there a way to sync this two mysql table with dynamodb.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/near-zero-downtime-migration-from-mysql-to-dynamodb/

It's also useful to create a view in your relational database which would mimic how your data would look making syncing multiple tables in your relational database with DynamoDB easier.